# No audio output via USB sound card

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb, audio, raspbian-jessie

I bought an external USB sound card for my Raspberry Pi because the sound quality of the built-in 3.5mm audio jack is not that good and I experienced a lot of noise.

The retailer of the sound card is called Ugreen and a lot of reviews on the internet state that the device should instantly work with the Raspberry Pi 3 without further configuration.

This is the output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I'm running a fresh installation of `2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie` on my Pi. If I run `raspi-config` and check the audio settings, I only have the following options:

```
0 Auto
1 Force 3.5mm ('headphone') jack
2 Force HDMI
```

I already tried all the options without any success. My speakers are working perfectly fine with the built-in 3.5mm connector. But not with the USB sound card. The speakers are powered via USB and the audio signal goes directly to the 3.5mm slot of the USB sound card which is connected to a USB slot on my Raspberry Pi.

I don't know what I can do now to get the sound card working.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to change the language in Raspbian and post the output of `aplay -l` in English?

Comment: Done, sorry for the circumstances.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that English might not be your native language, but its the language used by default on the site. I appreciate that you took the time to make the edit and I hope your problem gets resolved.

Comment: What applications are you intending to use for sound playback? Is there a reason to stick to Jessie (8) instead of Buster (10)?

Answer (score 1):

All Sound Cards should require at the very least 1 line of configuration in the `/boot/config.txt`

You have 2 options of getting things to work

1. Edit your `/boot/config.txt` and find the line `dtparam=audio=on` and change it to `dtparam=audio=off`
2. Create a file `/etc/asound.conf` or `~/.asoundrc` with the following:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what that dtparam is doing? (I.e. why does disabling audio work?) Also, now the alsa.config is in `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`.

Comment: USB audio interfaces _do not require_ any modification to boot configuration. They work automatically if they are class compliant.

Comment: Option 1 did not work after reboot, but Option 2 worked after ALSA restart. I used sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils stop; sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils start to reload the new ~/.asoundrc instead of rebooting. [Debian bookworm/sid + Openbox running on PI-4B]

Answer (score 0):

Your system is setup to have hw:1,0 as the USB device. I get this hw string by noting the output of aplay -l, where card 1 is the USB card and device 0 is the only listed device.

You should be able to playback over the USB card using :

aplay -D hw:1,0

Incidentally you may be interested in various other GPIO sound cards available for this Pi, check here for a short list :
http://elinux.org/index.php?title=RPi_Expansion_Boards#Sound

Comment: Is there no way to get my sound card into the raspi-config? I don't know what `aplay -D hw:1,0` is supposed to do but nothing happens. And the aplay man page doesn't help me either.

Comment: aplay is ALSA player, an audio play command. Did you specify the file name you want to play ? aplay -D hw:1,0 file.wav

Comment: I need to play mp3 because the wave files are to big and they cause stuttering.

Comment: Oh ok, try to use play (sox), mplayer or avplay for files which aplay doesn't handle.

Comment: omxplayer is also plays mp3. try: 
omxplayer -o alsa:plughw:1,0 yourmp3.mp3

Answer (score 0):

I tried `aplay -D plughw:1 file.wav`, and this command worked for me. This "plug" before "hw" for me is necessary.

Comment: "plug" lets you make software conversation about samplerate etc.