# Route Audio Output Through USB Audio Jack

Tags: audio, pi-zero, shairplay

I've an rPi Zero that I want to connect to my speakers to utilise it as an AirPlay receiver via Shairport.

I've made the same setup with my Model B+ and it works great. However, even though I made the same setup for my Zero, I can't seem to get the audio routed correctly since my B+ routes it via HDMI(the default) and I need the Zero to output it as analog.

**Hardware Setup:**

rPi Zero has a dedicated power connection. The data connection is connected to a USB Hub. And the hub connects the Wi-Fi adapter along with the USB to audio/microphone jacks converter.

**Software Setup:**
I've `[Shairport-sync][1]` installed and configured. My iPhone recognises it and can send the music. However nothing comes out of my speakers.

---

I know that I need to use `amixer` to route my audio, however, the command `amixer cset numid=3 1` yielded no success.

Here is the output of some related commands:

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`amixer controls`:

```
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Route'
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Switch'
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
numid=5,iface=PCM,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
numid=4,iface=PCM,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
```

What should I do to correctly route my audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out what to do.

The problem was some ALSA config files have been moved around and the tutorials I've looked up until the question were out-of-date.

[This post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80072/how-can-i-use-an-external-usb-sound-card-and-set-it-as-default)'s accepted answer, helped me solve it.