# ALSA input error (snd_pcm_open): No such file or directory - Problem with running Pd with ALSA

Tags: pi-3, audio, alsa, puredata

I am pretty new to Raspberry Pi, so sorry if I might be not clear on something.
I am trying to set the Raspberry Pi 3 to work running a Pure Data patch while communicating with two Arduino UNO, and getting it work just plugging it, so running the patch auto-starting after boot.
There are so many things I would like to ask, but I'll remain strict to the topic, also one of my first problem.
I switched to Patchbox OS cause I need a minimal system for audio working.
I am now using Pure Data running with jack (Pd->media->jack) cause it is not working with ALSA, but it seems to me that running jack is not the properly way: clicks and pops are showing up also if CPU meter is between 15% and 25%.
So I started searching for some solution.
I found in this site another related-question with a well explained answer:
[here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80072/how-can-i-use-an-external-usb-sound-card-and-set-it-as-default?newreg=06035c899054409280680208f0d2e2c4).
The problem with that comes just in the first steps, after calling

```
 patch@patchbox:~ $ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835_alsa - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
 1 [USB            ]: USB-Audio - Scarlett 2i4 USB
                      Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB at usb-3f980000.usb-1.5, high speed
```

I call amixer this is the results:

```
amixer -c 1
Simple mixer control 'Internal Validity',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
```

So the system is not recognising real ins and outs of my audio interface.
Also there is this problem with Pd, that when I chose ALSA as driver (Pd->media->ALSA) I get the problem reported on the title [ALSA input error (snd_pcm_open): No such file or directory]
I hope I have been clear,
Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

I've searched the Pd mailinglist archive for this ALSA error and found this post, [Re: [PD] alsa : Invalid value for card](https://lists.puredata.info/pipermail/pd-list/2016-12/117189.html), by IOhannes zmölning:

> iirc, there's a problem if the cards are not in consecuritve order,
>   starting with 0.
>
> e.g. my devices are
>
> ```
> $ cat /proc/asound/cards
>  0 [DSP            ]: H-DSP - Hammerfall DSP
>                       RME Hammerfall HDSP 9652 at 0xf3100000, irq 22
>  1 [MID            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID
>                       HDA Intel MID at 0xf3420000 irq 33
>  2 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
>                       HDA NVidia at 0xf3000000 irq 17
> $
> ```
>
> which means I have 3 devices with IDs 0, 1 & 2.
>
> if however, you have something like
>
> ```
> $ cat /proc/asound/cards
>  1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
>                       HDA NVidia at 0xf3000000 irq 17
> $
> ```
>
> then you are missing the device `#0`, and Pd gets into trouble.
>
> a couple of workarounds:
>
> - use jack to talk with the soundcard, so Pd doesn't need to know
> - make sure that the card numbers start with 0 (and are consecutive, in case you want to access a not-first card); this most likely
>     involves tweaking some kernel module parameters (for the soundcards to
>     be loaded), and maybe some udev rules.

a [reply](https://lists.puredata.info/pipermail/pd-list/2016-12/117190.html) by Nicolas Montgermont shows a solution:

> editing `/lib/modprobe.d/aliases.conf` and changing:
>
> ```
> options snd-usb-audio index=-2
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> options snd-usb-audio index=0
> ```
>
> make the card number to 0 and works in pd with alsa.

That said, in your provided `cat /proc/asound/cards` output the cards are in consecutive order, so the problem might actually be different.