# Play audio on rPi Zero WH using USB speakers

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, usb-audio, speakers

I would like to configure a Phoniebox (play music using RFID reader). I configured pretty much everything, the interface works and indicates that I'm reading the music file, but the rPi doesn't play any sound on the USB speakers. My hypothesis is that the problem is either:

- with my audio interface configuration
- with the USb-to-jack adapter
- somewhere else?

I did go through and implemented this topic: [How can I use an external USB sound-card and set it as default?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80072/how-can-i-use-an-external-usb-sound-card-and-set-it-as-default)
The problem is that when I try to verify the codec, the examples are disabled and I have no idea what to try more than that:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ vcgencmd codec_enabled MPG2
MPG2=disabled
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ vcgencmd codec_enabled WVC1
WVC1=disabled
```

On one hand I think the card seems to exist:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ cat /proc/asound/cards
 1 [Audio          ]: USB-Audio -  USB Audio
                      Generic  USB Audio at usb-20980000.usb-1.2, full speed
```

On the other hand the aplay command doesn't give anything, and I don't know how to read the lsusb output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID ffff:0035
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 001f:0b21
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 214b:7250
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ amixer -c 1
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono: Playback 63 [25%] [on]
```

FYI I also took a look at the amixer command, but I don't know what to do with the results:

```
  pi@raspberrypi:/ $ amixer scontrols
  Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  pi@raspberrypi:/ $ amixer controls
  numid=3,iface=CARD,name='Keep Interface'
  numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Switch'
  numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
```

I searched the interface, but did not find anything. Even here https://learn.adafruit.com/usb-audio-cards-with-a-raspberry-pi/figure-out-your-chipset all the commands for the different dmesg don't yield anything.
Should I change the configuration somehow? Should I buy another adapter (I don't know when you can talk about a "soundcard" instead of an "adapter")? Should I ditch it all and buy a rPi with jack output directly?

My hardware is:

- speakers https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00JRW0M32/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_il_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1638&creative=6742&creativeASIN=B00JRW0M32&linkCode=as2&tag=diebarnfeld-21
- USB-to-jack adapter https://www.amazon.de/JSAUX-Audio-Adapter-USB-Soundkarte-Aux-Headset-kompatibel/dp/B08B1KK54P/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2VVNUFRE2IVXK&keywords=usb+to+jack&qid=1697206303&sprefix=usb+to+jack%2Caps%2C102&sr=8-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: apparently the hardware may be at fault, I gave a try with this USB sound card and it works :)
https://www.amazon.de/dp/B089YXDFC9?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details